# SQL query for parent with specific values in child set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, set-theory

I am trying to return just the parent where the set of children contain multiple specific records. Given this table:

```
Product   State
-------   -----
111       AZ
111       CA
111       UT
222       AZ
222       WA
333       CA
```

I want find the list of `Product` that have both a `AZ` child record and a `CA` child record, even if it also has other records. Which would return ...

```
Product
-------
111
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select product  
  from table 
 where state in ('az','ca')  
 group by product 
having count(distinct(state)) = 2


select distinct product  
  from table 
 where state = 'az'
INTERSECT 
select distinct product  
  from table 
 where state = 'ca'  


select distinct t1.product  
  from table t1 
  join table t2 
    on t1.product = t2.product 
   and t1.state = 'az'
   and t2.state = 'ca'
```

The last is probably going to be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product 
FROM table 
GROUP BY product 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN State 'AZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN State 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates (which there does happen to be in my case)?

Comment: @theChrisMarsh : Then you should check this values separately. Updated.