# NHibernate: Filter result on one-to-many join

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I am trying to filter a query based on the values of all the objects on the left join. My objects are defined as such:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public virtual long Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ISet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public virtual long Id{get;set;}
    public virtual string Ingredient {get;set;}
    public virtual decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

And they are mapped like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Recipe"  table="Recipe">
        <set name="Ingredients" inverse="true">
            <key column="RecipeId" />
            <one-to-many class="Recipe" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Ingredient" dynamic-update="true" table="Ingredient" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id" column="Id" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
         </id>
        <property name="Ingredient" not-null="true" lazy="false"/>
        <property name= "Amount" column= "Amount" type="decimal" />    
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

What I want to do is to be able to search a Recipe based on the ingredients. For example say I want to find all recipes where the ingredients are

```
Ingredient | Amount
Sugar      |  100
Flour      |  200
Eggs       |    2
```

I am not really sure how I would even do that in SQL. I tried something like this:

```
public Recipe FindRecipeByIngredients(ISet<Ingredient> ingredients)
{
    return this.Session.QueryOver<Recipe>()
            .Where(r => r.Ingredients.All(c => ingredients.Any(i => i.Ingredient == r.Ingredient && i.Amount == r.ConcentrAmountation))).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

but Nhibernate doesn't know how to convert All into SQL.
I was thinking it might be possible to do the search in reverse, searching in the Ingredient table for all records with the correct ingredient and amount, but then I would come up with all recipes which have those ingredients as well as others.
Can this be done using SQL queries or do I have to accept the fact that I'll have to pull up all the records (with minimal filtering) and then filter them in the code?

(As a bonus I will also have to, in the future, filter similar recipes, so recipies in which the amounts are almost equal so maybe amount <1.05refAmount && amount >0.95refAmount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to find a fairly good solution this. The sql query I need to run is:

```
    SELECT RecipeId
  FROM Ingredient
GROUP BY RecipeId 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Ingredient = 'Ingredient1'  AND Amount = 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN Ingredient = 'Ingredient2'  AND Amount = 300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND ...
```

I had a couple more problems converting it into something nhibernate would construct correctly and ended up with this:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Ingredients>()
                .SetProjection(Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Property<Ingredient>(i => i.Recipe.Id)));

foreach (Ingredient ingredient in recipe.Ingredients)
{
    criteria.Add(
        Restrictions.Eq(
            Projections.Sum(
                Projections.Conditional(
                    Restrictions.Where<Ingredient>(i => i.Ingredient == ingredient.Ingredient && i.Amount == ingredient.Amount)
                    Projections.Constant(1),
                    Projections.Constant(0)
                 )
             ),
         1));
}
```

Which returns the above query. I tried doing it with Restrictions.Conjuntction, or using QueryOver, but the conditional query ended up in a WHERE condition before the GROUP BY rather than the HAVING condition after the GROUP BY resulting in an incorrect sql query. It might be a bug in Nhibernate (similar to [NH-2863](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2863)), but I'm not sure.
If anyone finds a more efficient way to solve this I'd me glad to update it.
Also the answer is based on these answers on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24334034/5426336

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3556840/5426336